# Code Signing Certificate Flag

Tags: code-signing, code-signing-certificate

Is this `MICROSOFT_ROOT_CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_CHECK_APPLICATION_ROOT_FLAG` flag used for code signing supported on **Windows XP**, **Windows Vista** and **Windows 7**?

When I am using this flag in `CertVerifyCertificateChainPolicy` function on above operating systems, I am getting

> CERT_E_UNTRUSTEDROOT
>   error.

It is working fine for me on **Windows 8** and above though.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377163(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The `dwFlags` member of the `CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_PARA` structure pointed to by the pPolicyStatus parameter can contain the `MICROSOFT_ROOT_CERT_CHAIN_POLICY_CHECK_APPLICATION_ROOT_FLAG flag`, **which causes this function to also check for the Microsoft application root "*Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2011***".

So make sure those older systems have "Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2011" package installed.  For more info, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931125

---

To Manually install the certificates

1. Download http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/rootsupd.exe
2. Extract the files using the command rootsupd.exe /c /t:C:\temp\extroot
3. from c:\temp\extroot run the following 4 commands (from an elevated prompt)

   updroots.exe authroots.sst
   updroots.exe updroots.sst
   updroots.exe -l roots.sst
   updroots.exe -d delroots.sst

Comment: Thanks Tim. But I am using for desktop application, which is used by users present across world. So how we can make user install "Microsoft Root Certificate Authority 2011" package on their system. It would be difficult to use this solution. Is there some way to make code work on lower OS.

Comment: first i would validate this on your test Win7 machine; then if it is true you need to ask yourself if you really want to use this flag or not knowing what Microsoft has stated.

Comment: I have tested the same on Windows Vista and Windows 7, it is failing. I need this flag as Microsoft has changed the code signing certificate. To validate new cert I want this flag.

Comment: do you mean that you installed the certificate update on both Win7 and Vista and it is still failing after manually updating the certificate files?

Comment: also, is the certificate you used for signing a test certificate or a valid certificate?

Comment: No I haven't install certificate update on Windows 7 and Vista. Will try this option. And I am using valid certificate for code signing